# Run a cfquery inside of a query output

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, cfquery

I am getting weird unexpected results when I try to run a cfquery inside of the output of a previous query.

Example:

```
<cfoutput query="reportInfo">
  <tr>
    <td>#id#</td>
    <td>#name#</td>    
    <cfif Status EQ 'Complete'>
      <cfquery name="submitInfo" datasource="RC">
        SELECT  *
        FROM    Action_Log
        WHERE Form_ID = '#id#'
        AND Action = 'Complete' OR Action = 'Saved'
      </cfquery>    
      <cfset startStamp = submitInfo.Action_Time>
      <cfoutput>startStamp</cfoutput>    
      <td>#startStamp#</td>
    <cfelse>
      <td>No Completion Date</td>
    </cfif>
  </tr>
</cfoutput>
```

When "StartStamp" is output to the page it is shown once for each count in the loop and it does this for each ID so there is a lot of extra.

**I thought it should only run the submitInfo query once every time the contain query (reportInfo) output loops through but that is not happening.**

Comment: The query will only be ran one time per record in `reportInfo`. I'm not sure I understand what you are expecting.

Comment: as an aside your query is probably not written as you expect. If you want to query for the form_ID and the action being either complete or saved you need `()` around your two action clauses. In addition you should be able to do this all in one query without the nested query.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you should get rid of the inner cfoutput tags ie `<cfoutput>startStamp</cfoutput>`. They are only needed when using the cfoutput group feature. Having said that, querying within a loop should be avoided. Most times you can achieve the same result with a simple JOIN. Without knowing more about the first query, I see no reason you cannot do that here.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the notes and comments. I am going to explore building the whole thing in one query. After removing the cfoutput from startStamp I am already seeing an improvement. Before the numbers were duplicating (best way to describe it) every time through the main query.

Comment: That was due to the extra set of `cfoutput` tags.  When you nest cfoutput tags CF thinks you want to use the [`group` attribute](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfoutput) (which "..eliminates adjacent duplicate rows when data is sorted").  Hence the repeats :-) Though removing the extra tags solves the issue, switching to a single JOIN is definitely the way to go. It is much more efficient than hitting the database on each iteration - for every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Expanded from comments ...)

> `<cfoutput>startStamp</cfoutput>`

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you should get rid of the inner `cfoutput tags`. Those are only needed when using the (frequently misunderstood) [`<cfoutput group="...">` feature](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfoutput). It is normally used to eliminate duplicates from *sorted* data. However, if the data is *not* sorted properly - or is grouped incorrectly - it can produce the kind of results you described. (If you are not familiar with grouping, see [this example of creating an A-Z type listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728189/creating-an-alphabetical-indexed-list-coldfusion-microsoft-sql-server/13729384#13729384)).

Having said that, querying within a loop should be avoided. Most times you can achieve the same result with a simple `JOIN`. Without knowing more about the first query, I see no reason you cannot do that here.

In psuedo-sql something along these lines. It uses an [`OUTER JOIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) to retrieve all records from the first table, but only the values from Action_Log that have a matching ID and status of "Complete" or "Saved".

```
SELECT  t1.ID
        , t1.Name
        , al.Action_Time AS CompletionDate
FROM    SomeTable t1
      LEFT JOIN Action_Log al 
                ON al.Form_ID = t1.ID 
                AND t1.Status = 'Complete'
                AND al.Action IN ('Complete','Saved')
```